# not redirecting a certain file in base folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If have a mod write which works fine, but I want it to **not apply** to one certain file ("somefile.php") **in the base folder**. All other files (especially "somefile.php" files in subfolders) shall be effected by the rule.

I tried adding a RewriteCond for this case before the RewriteRule but I could not figure out the correct syntax. My last wrong try is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^$)/somefile.php
```

I think it has to be something like that. **Can you correct this syntax?**

**Edit:**

Here is a reduced version of my rewrite mod (RewriteCond modified according to first answer):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/|/index\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ main.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My base folder is: //localhost/somefolder_but_i_dont_know_its_name/

**Edit 2:**

I found a workaround (it does not answer my syntax question but seems to solve the underlying problem):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)somefile\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ - [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ main.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```